# Qt - Horizontal spacer

Tags: c++, qt

I want to ask about the `horizontal spacer` in `Qt`.

I couldn't get its effect when adding it to the form for example through the `Qt designer`.

Why do we use the horizontal spacer? What is its purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's used to prevent widgets from stretching or moving across the window.

Suppose you have a window a with a horizontal layout and the following widgets besides each other:

```
[LABEL EDIT]
```

If you resize the window, the widgets will be stretched with the window.  In this case, the edit widget will probably be stretched, and you get this:

```
[LABEL E   D   I   T]
```

You can make the edit widget fixed, but then you get this after a resize

```
[LABEL          EDIT        ]
```

To keep the edit control on its place, use a horizontal spacer:

```
[LABEL EDIT SPACER]
```

If the window is now resized, you will get this:

```
[LABEL EDIT S  P  A  C  E  R]
```